# Can anyone tell me if this means something

Tags: string, random, passwords

My group of friends own a teamspeak server and one day they kicked me out and gave me this string and said it has the password i have 0 context as to what this is so i was hoping someone could give me a hand the string is: U3BvbmdlaXNhZHVtZHVtIQ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a ***Base64*** encoded string. 
You can decode it using some decoding site, eg.:

- https://www.base64decode.org/

Your actual `U3BvbmdlaXNhZHVtZHVtIQ==` string will decode into: `Spongeisadumdum!` ... witch more than a password it looks like that your friends are teasing at you, **Sponge**

(*It is probably an entertaining joke of your friends without bad intentions, my suggestion is that you take it with humor and have fun with it* )

Comment: lol yeah thank you very much i want sure even where to begin with that.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to find the answer you were looking for would be to google something relevant to the string. It looks like gibberish but since it ends with ==, you could google something like 'Code ending with =='.

Googling that gives you a search result with the first link being to a base64 decoder website. Having the resourcefulness to find patterns and ask the right questions is a valuable skill.

Comment: _"Having the resourcefulness to find patterns and ask the right questions is a valuable skill"_ 

Excellent phrase. 

Definitely a valuable skill since civilization began to use language...nowadays it could simply be translated into (and perhaps more useful): _"know to googling"_ 